# How to include a custom SASS file in a Vaadin 14 application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, maven, sass, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm developing a Vaadin 14 app on Maven, so I'm using `vaadin-maven-plugin` which, according to Vaadin's v14 starter app:

> Takes care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in package.json and main.js files. It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.

After running the app I got the `package.json` file and the `node-modules` on the root dir. I performed `npm install bootstrap` afterwards and created a custom SCSS file inside `src/main/webapp/frontend/`, with a few handpicked `@import` instructions to get my own Bootstrap build.

Vaadin's documentation about [Including Style Sheets](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-include-css.html) doesn't mention anything regarding SCSS. **How can I get Vaadin's Maven plugin to compile my SCSS file so I can import the resulting CSS file into my app?**

Comment: I do not know about vaadin maven plugin. But you can use following plugin and automate almost anything with proper goal and phase settings. https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Kaspar Scherrer's answer, I was able to generate a custom build of Twitter Bootstrap to include as CSS on my Vaadin 14 app by performing the following steps:

1. Include Bootstrap’s source Sass and JavaScript files via npm, running `npm install bootstrap` on the CLI in the project's root dir;
2. Setup [libsass-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gitlab.haynes/libsass-maven-plugin) on my project's `pom.xml`:

```xml
<!-- SASS compiler -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.gitlab.haynes</groupId>
  <artifactId>libsass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.21</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <inputPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/frontend/sass/</inputPath>
    <includePath>${basedir}/node_modules/</includePath>
    <outputPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/frontend/css/</outputPath>
    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

3. Created the custom SASS file, named `webapp-bootstrap.scss` in this example, inside the dir set on `inputPath`:

```sass
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

// Required
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";

@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/clearfix";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/deprecate";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/grid-framework";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/hover";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/screen-reader";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/text-emphasis";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/text-hide";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins/text-truncate";


// Optional
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/align";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/clearfix";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/display";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/flex";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/float";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/position";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/screenreaders";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/sizing";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/spacing";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/text";
```

4. Included the generated stylesheets on my app by using an annotation `@StyleSheet("css/webapp-bootstrap.css")`.

Comment: Thanks for posting confirmation that it works, and for the configuration of the plugin. I'd say you've earned to accept your own answer, I dont mind ;) Cheers

Comment: Done. Thanks for the inspiration :)

Answer (score 2):

In vaadins [theming documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/migration/6-theming.html) it mentions that

> Vaadin 14 itself isn’t using Sass, but you can of course use it for your own application theming if you want to. You’ll have to setup the sass-compiler workflow yourself, but there are Maven Plugins available for this.

After a quick search I found this [sass-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.geodienstencentrum.maven/sass-maven-plugin/3.7.2) which will probably do what you need; compile your sass/scss files to css before packaging.

As pointed out in comments, there is also the [libsass-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gitlab.haynes/libsass-maven-plugin/0.2.21).

I myself have not used this yet (will try to, once I get some time) so I can't tell you how to best configure said plugin. But I'm sure that once it's configured correctly, this is the way to use SCSS/SASS with Vaadin 14

Comment: @Kasper Scherrer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The github repository of the Maven plugin you mentioned has been archived: "Version 3.7.2 is likely the final and last release of this plugin as (Ruby) Sass has reached End of Life."

I searched some more and went with the LibSass Maven plugin listed in https://sass-lang.com/libsass#java. Please update your answer with a reference for this plugin so I can accept it.

Comment: Edited it in. But i noticed that the latest version of libsass-maven-plugin is one year older than the latest of sass-maven-plugin. I have tried neither yet so I can't say  which is better. Once I get to try them out myself I will update this answer.

Comment: You got the wrong libsass-maven-plugin, it's https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gitlab.haynes/libsass-maven-plugin which was forked from the one you added and has newer releases.